# How do I serve html,css and js as a post response while using CORS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Trying to understand the best method to send html,css, js files back to the client via a Post request.
I'm running express,react.

What I have so far is a basic post route, that returns the compiled component with data (using handlebars) as a response. However the event handlers, css and js are absent. I'm not sure how to serve these along with the HTML as a response to an AJAX POST request on another domain.

I'm using webpack for SSR and figured this would work much the same but it doesn't.

Here is what i have so far...this just returns the html from my react component.

```
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const theHtml = `
  <html>
  <head><title>My First SSR</title>
  <link href='http://localhost:8080/app.css'></link>
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/vendor.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>My First Server Side Render</h1>
  <div id="reactele">{{{reactele}}}</div>
 </body>
  </html>
  `;

  const hbsTemplate = hbs.compile(theHtml);
  const reactComp = renderToString(<App />);
  const htmlToSend = hbsTemplate({ reactele: reactComp });
  res.send(htmlToSend);
});
```

The above works and is returned just without js,css event handlers etc..
here is the App component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      msg: ""
    };
  }

  //Handlers
  handleButtonClick = e => {
    const nameLen = this.state.name.length;
    if (nameLen > 0) {
      this.setState({
        msg: `You name has ${nameLen} characters including space`
      });
    }
  };

  handleTextChange = e => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({ name: "", msg: "" });
  };
  //End Handlers

  render() {
    let msg;

    if (this.state.msg !== "") {
      msg = <p>{this.state.msg}</p>;
    } else {
      msg = "I have a state of none";
    }
    return (
      //do something here where there is a button that will replace the text
      <div>
        <header className="App-header">
        {/* <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> */}

        {/* <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> */}
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
        <label>Your name </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="txtName"
          name="txtName"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleTextChange}
        />
        <button id="btnSubmit" onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>
          Calculate Name Length
        </button>
        <button id="btnReset" onClick={this.handleReset}>
          Reset All
        </button>
        <hr />
        {msg}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

On the client side i'm just appending the html to a blank page. 
A few questions,

How do I maintain the eventhandlers on the requested html?
How do send the .css and .js along as well?

For some context, I'd like to avoid having to place and maintain 'client' code on my front-end server? My hope was something like webpack would handle this for me?

Thanks for any tips/suggestions.

EDIT:: To clarify this works if I access the route directly. I get the correlating js and css. Just not via a post request from another domain. I assume I'm missing some fundamental udnerstanding how the dom is maintained and scripts run.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a static directory and a view renderer.

In your app.js or where ever you have initialized your express instance, add the following

```js
var hbs = require('hbs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Now you can just put your html in a hbs file in a folder called 'views' and just return it like

```js
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
 res.render('index.hbs', {variable: 'value'});
});
```

For the static assets add the following lines

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and put your js and css or images or whatever static files you want in a folder named 'public' in your project root. These will be accessible at http://localhost:8080/app.js

Comment: I Rohith, I do have these already setup though not shown in my code. My issue isn't that this doesn't work but when serving to an existing page via a post, only the html is displayed, the associated functions,css etc aren't present.

Comment: Most AJAX APIs use the browser's `.innerHTML` to set the content. And that will strip the **<head> <title>** and **<html>** tags, but the scripts will execute. But, since the head is stripped I am guessing they aren't loading?

Comment: The way you're setup, I think if SSR is the goal, you can be up and running with Next.JS in no time. It's basically React but with SSR.

Comment: I found my problem and your comment helped me see it. I was not loading my HTML response into the DOM correctly. This was causing  the scripts to not evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was on client end (my second domain). It was how i was loading the html into the DOM, my old method was inneHTML on the body. Simple answer is this doesnt work.

I had to load it in another way, I chose to use jquery's .html(), this triggers the dom to evaluate the scripts etc.

@RohithBalaji your comment helped me find my issue.

> Most AJAX APIs use the browser's .innerHTML to set the content. And
>   that will strip the   and  tags, but the scripts
>   will execute. But, since the head is stripped I am guessing they
>   aren't loading?